# Daemon threads scheduled on an ExecutorService; explain why this is bad form

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, daemon, executorservice

I'm comfortable with the idea of orderly shutdown on threads scheduled with an `ExectuorService`; that is to say, calling `shutdown` or `shutdownNow` will cause threads created on the pool to exit gracefully. If they respond to `interrupt` you can be sure finally etc will be called and you'll get a clean, predictable exit (where you can cleanup any resources etc).

However, if you've set your thread to be a daemon (via the executor's `ThreadFactory`) as below.

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(new ThreadFactory() {
   @Override
   public Thread newThread(Runnable runnable) {
      Thread thread = Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread(runnable);
      thread.setDaemon(true);
      return thread;
   }
});
```

after the main thread terminates, the VM will abruptly terminate any daemon threads. **In the example above, a (daemon) thread scheduled and then abruptly terminated will bypass any finally blocks and any interruptable methods won't throw `InterruptedException`**.

So, I tend to think that marking the threads used in a `ThreadPoolExecutor`'s pool as daemon is bad practice... my question is really about helping me vocalise *why*.

**Why is it bad practice (or not if you disagree) to use daemon threads in a `ExecutorService`'s thread pool? In particular I'm interested in describing the life-cycle of the VM shutdown with graceful shutdown (threads that have an interruption policy and play nicely) vs daemon threads.**

Expanding that last point, `finalize` on `ThreadPoolExecutor` will call `shutdown` on itself, but when it's using daemon threads, they could have terminated already if `finalize` was called by the VM. What's the behavior of the thread pool then? Can it be tricked into remaining alive (and so not exiting the VM) if underlying threads terminated abruptly?

Part of the reason I'm asking is because i've seen it used to bypass the need to shutdown the actual ExectorService. Can you think of scenarios where bypassing *its* shutdown life-cycle can have ill affect? So far, the only reason I can come up with for using daemons is to take a short cut and I want to appreciate any unexpected side affects it could cause.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> is it bad practice to use daemon threads in a ExecutorService's thread pool?

If the tasks sent to that particular `ExecutorService` are ok to be terminated abruptly, then why not, that's what daemon threads do. But generally, there are not many tasks that are ok to be terminated with no shutdown ceremonies at all, so you must know what you're doing if you opt to daemon threads.

`finalize()` is called when an object is *about to be garbage collected*. There are no guarantees on when, if ever, any particular object will be GCd, and `ThreadPoolExecutor` is no exception, so its `finalize()` may or may not be called. The behavior depends on the particular JRE implementation, and even with the same implementation, may vary from time to time.

Comment: surely, setting the thread pool itself to always use daemon threads constrains its usage? You'd be saying that any threads that get scheduled will have to be aware and ok with it... so if its for framework code, it's potentially limiting.

Comment: @Toby: Definitely the usage is constrained, so it should not be used as a general solution. At least the entry point to that particular pool should be strongly labeled with warning signs.

Answer (score 6):

Daemon threads can be useful, and if they weren't terminated abruptly, they wouldn't be so useful IMO.

Presumably we could imagine another type of thread, which are interrupted when no normal threads are running anymore, instead of being abruptly terminated. That may be a little convenient, but if you had to do any clean up at all, it's likely that you wanted to do an orderly clean up. This would limit the convenience of this feature.

On the other hand, if you had tasks that would not need any clean up at shutdown, deamon threads are quite convenient. And you wouldn't want to waste time waiting them to arrive at some specific state or risk a hang up on shutdown etc., because the reason you are using a deamon thread is because you don't need any kind of clean up. It would be a waste of time to execute anything if the app. is shutting down. If you care, then you shouldn't have used deamon threads.

It's no different with deamon thread pools. If that thread pool is doing tasks that do not need any clean up at shutdown, then it would make sense because of the convenience.

From the [JCiP book](http://jcip.net/):

> Daemon threads should be used sparinglyfew processing activities can be safely abandoned at any time with no cleanup. In particular, it is dangerous to use daemon threads for tasks that might perform any sort of I/O. Daemon threads are best saved for "housekeeping" tasks, such as a background thread that periodically removes expired entries from an in-memory cache

Answer (score 5):

I tend to have different pools for daemon and non-daemon threads.  Daemon pools tend to do recurring clean up jobs, monitoring and background tasks which don't matter if one or two is not executed.  Any task which is only meaningful while the application is still running is good to make a daemon thread task. e.g. GC threads are daemon threads.

Comment: sure, but why allow these to terminate without clean (for example) when you probably shutdown the well behaved pools programmatically? as in, why *not* call shutdown on the misc task/cleanup pool and not have them as daemons.

Comment: Because its something extra the developer needs to know to do which doesn't make any difference so probably won't be done consistently.

Comment: hmmm, not really seeing that... if you don't shutdown the executor, the VM wont exit. I'm thinking the developer has figured out he needs to call shutdown/Now by now so why bypass this for the special case pool that doesn't need a shutdown. I'd expect people to call shutdown on both..?

Comment: background tasks are often performed by libraries written by a different developer than the one who rites the main code which is performing the shutdown.  If you have more than one developer, he may not know to shutdown an executor which is hidden away in a library.